# Convert C# code to visual basic.net

Tags: vb.net

```
private void Convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (conversionType.Value)
            {
                case "temperature":
                    {
                        if (convertValue1)
                        {
                            textBox2.Text = "";
                            try
                            {
                      double fahrenheightValue = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                   double celsiusValue = (fahrenheightValue - 32) * (5.0 / 9.0);
                    textBox2.Text = celsiusValue.ToString("F");
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                textBlock2.Text = "Error";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            textBox1.Text = "";
                            try
                            {
                    double celsiusValue = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                    double fahrenheitValue = (celsiusValue * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32;
                                textBox1.Text = fahrenheitValue.ToString("F");
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                textBlock1.Text = "Error";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case "spoons":
                    {
                        if (convertValue1)
                        {
                            textBox2.Text = "";
                            try
                            {
                                double teaspoons = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                                double tablespoons = teaspoons / 3;
                                textBox2.Text = tablespoons.ToString("F");
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                textBlock2.Text = "Error";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            textBox1.Text = "";
                            try
                            {
                               double tablespoons = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                                double teaspoons = tablespoons * 3;
                                textBox1.Text = teaspoons.ToString("F");
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                textBlock1.Text = "Error";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            this.Focus();
        }
```

Comment: try some online converts and then fix what is not correct......

Comment: Use Telerik (www.telerik.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Convert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Select Case conversionType.Value
        Case "temperature"
            If True Then
                If convertValue1 Then
                    textBox2.Text = ""
                    Try
                        Dim fahrenheightValue As Double = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text)
                        Dim celsiusValue As Double = (fahrenheightValue - 32) * (5.0 / 9.0)
                        textBox2.Text = celsiusValue.ToString("F")
                    Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
                        textBlock2.Text = "Error"
                    End Try
                Else
                    textBox1.Text = ""
                    Try
                        Dim celsiusValue As Double = Double.Parse(textBox2.Text)
                        Dim fahrenheitValue As Double = (celsiusValue * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32
                        textBox1.Text = fahrenheitValue.ToString("F")
                    Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
                        textBlock1.Text = "Error"
                    End Try
                End If
            End If
            Exit Select

        Case "spoons"
            If True Then
                If convertValue1 Then
                    textBox2.Text = ""
                    Try
                        Dim teaspoons As Double = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text)
                        Dim tablespoons As Double = teaspoons / 3
                        textBox2.Text = tablespoons.ToString("F")
                    Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
                        textBlock2.Text = "Error"
                    End Try
                Else
                    textBox1.Text = ""
                    Try
                        Dim tablespoons As Double = Double.Parse(textBox2.Text)
                        Dim teaspoons As Double = tablespoons * 3
                        textBox1.Text = teaspoons.ToString("F")
                    Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
                        textBlock1.Text = "Error"
                    End Try
                End If
            End If
            Exit Select
    End Select
    Me.Focus()
End Sub

'=======================================================
'Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
'Conversion powered by NRefactory.
'Twitter: @telerik
'Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
'=======================================================
```